# Magento1 Feefo widget js conflict with prototype.js

Tags: php, magento, widget, conflict

I want to display feefo  carousal widget on my website. For that I have generate the widget code and trying to add on my magento 1.9 website. But Feefo widget JS is conflict with the prototype.js and raised the below error in console,

Error 1

```
feefo-widget.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.map callback must be a function
    at Array.map (feefo-widget.js:53)
    at Array.toArray (prototype.js:1002)
    at t.exports (feefo-widget.js:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (feefo-widget.js:41)
    at o (feefo-widget.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (feefo-widget.js:41)
    at o (feefo-widget.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (feefo-widget.js:48)
    at o (feefo-widget.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (feefo-widget.js:48)
map @ feefo-widget.js:53
toArray @ prototype.js:1002
t.exports @ feefo-widget.js:48
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:41
o @ feefo-widget.js:1
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:41
o @ feefo-widget.js:1
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:48
o @ feefo-widget.js:1
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:48
o @ feefo-widget.js:1
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:53
o @ feefo-widget.js:1
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:1
(anonymous) @ feefo-widget.js:1
```

Error 2

```
enter code here
feefo.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: feefoWidget is not defined
    at HTMLScriptElement.feefoWidgetScript.onload (feefo.js:8)
```

Please help me to fix this issue? I have tried but no solution found.

Answer (score 0):

Feefo official response is to upgrade prototype

https://support.feefo.com/support/solutions/articles/8000062222-can-feefo-widgets-be-used-on-protype-websites-

> Feefo integration widgets and carousels are supported on websites using Prototype JavaScript Framework 1.7.3.
>
> Websites using earlier versions of the Prototype JavaScript Framework may experience unpredictable behaviour and therefore we would advise upgrading to the latest version.

http://prototypejs.org/

Obviously that could cause more issues that it solves bit it's a potential answer

There is an extension which might do the job

https://github.com/leytech/Leytech_PrototypeUpdate

I've not personally tested it but looking over the code it seems viable.